# Reference to object is ambiguous

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal, couchbase-lite

I am getting Xcode compile error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: reference to 'Session' is ambiguous
/ProjectDirectory/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework/Headers/OneSignal.h:244:29: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Session'
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Session) {
                            ^
/Users/MyUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-apoiuurqrcguucdjqrtzfoqixrcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UserData.framework/Headers/UserData-Swift.h:245:12: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Session'
@interface Session : CBLModel
```

It seems Xcode threw this error, because project has class `Session` which inherits `CBLModel` (CouchBase document) and project uses OneSignal framework.

If object Session, does not inherit `CBLModel`, Xcode compiles without major issues.

It seems, like due to CouchBase, Xcode somehow generates additional files?

Xcode provides `Candidate found by name lookup is 'Session'`:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8UserData7Session")
@interface Session : CBLModel
@property (nonatomic) int64_t created;
@end
```

And

```
/* OneSignal Influence Types */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Session) {
    DIRECT,
    INDIRECT,
    UNATTRIBUTED,
    DISABLED
};
```

Any ideas how to solve issue without renaming `Session`?

Comment: I doubt this is possible, and this is why it is strongly recommended to always prefix Objective-C types since it has no concept of namespacing and such, especially with such a ubiquitous name like `Session`

Comment: @Xernox have you tried renaming the session object?

Comment: @Jay Yes, I've renamed my Session. That seemed like the only fix

Comment: `UserData.framework/Headers/UserData-Swift.h` and `OneSignal.framework/Headers/OneSignal.h` both does not looks like a CBL framework classes. Are you sure, changing the inheritance from CBLModel alone is fixing the ambiguous class name error?

Comment: I've renamed my own Session, which did inherit CBL document. 

As soon my object inherits CBL - that's it, it can not be named Session.